# How to add wildcard mapping in entry of webpack

Tags: node.js, webpack

I need to webpack all the js file in the script folder.I tried this

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loaders: ["babel-loader"],
      }
    ],
  },
  entry: "./src/scripts/*.js",
  output: {
    path: './src/build',
    filename: '[name].js'
  }
};
```

I am getting  error like this,

```
ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./s
rc/scripts/* in E:\Web project\ReactJS\react-tutorial
resolve file
  E:\Web project\ReactJS\react-tutorial\src\scripts\* doesn't exist
  E:\Web project\ReactJS\react-tutorial\src\scripts\*.webpack.js doesn't exist
  E:\Web project\ReactJS\react-tutorial\src\scripts\*.web.js doesn't exist
  E:\Web project\ReactJS\react-tutorial\src\scripts\*.js doesn't exist
  E:\Web project\ReactJS\react-tutorial\src\scripts\*.json doesn't exist
resolve directory
  E:\Web project\ReactJS\react-tutorial\src\scripts\* doesn't exist (directory d
efault file)
  E:\Web project\ReactJS\react-tutorial\src\scripts\*\package.json doesn't exist
 (directory description file)
```

It is not searching for all the js file instead it is searching for *.js like that.Help me out what I missed

Comment: A wildcard doesn't lead to a clean solution. You can always have a main file to import all other libraries inside the directory and point webpack entry to it.

Comment: For `webpack ^5.80.0`, see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/76625271/6463558

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `entry` value should resolve to a specific file, or a list of specific files.

From the [webpack docs](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#entry):

> If you pass a string: The string is resolved to a module which is
>   loaded upon startup.
>
> If you pass an array: All modules are loaded upon startup. The last
>   one is exported.

If you are simply trying to define one module, edit your `entry` value to point to your main application file and then require other modules from that.

If you really want to bundle all files from a directory, see [arseniews answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34545812/3252835)

Comment: I don't know if that's their situation, but it [sometimes](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/multiple-entry-points) makes sense to have multiple entry points.
But yeah in general, on entry point is enough.

Comment: Sure, it's possible to define more than one but you'd still want to explicitly say which they are. Otherwise you'd end up with a potentially large number of entry points and corresponding bundles which is almost certainly not what's desired here.

Comment: The answer given by @Víctor González below works nicely.

Answer (score 116):

Having one or few entry points should be enough for most of use cases, but if you **really** want to bundle up all files from directory you can use following:

As explained here: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/370

```
var glob = require("glob");
// ...
entry: glob.sync("./src/scripts/*.js")
```

Comment: glob.sync("./src/scripts/**/*.js") works recursively on any subdirectories

Comment: @HasanGilak I would imagine that the above glob is done so on purpose, to include **only** the root files. You don't really want Webpack to process all files, even those that are required from modules higher up the chain.

Comment: no. this works fine while webpack itself require higher dependencies by just seeing import statement.

Comment: While it would be kinda behaviour for '.js', this can come in very handy for `css|less|sass|...` (for those of us, who abandon gulp for an all-webpack-solution...)

Comment: Whenever I use glob , it gives error in webpack : Invalid config object ,webpack has been initialized using object that doesn't match the API schema.

Comment: @DebasishJena In this case the glob call didn't return any results (an empty array), most likely due to a wrong glob pattern. Webpack does not seem to like an empty entry point hence the error.

Answer (score 17):

Webpack is expecting a [list of files](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/#entry) for the `entry` configuration, not a [glob pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)).

You'll have to list the files manually, or automatically with this code snippet

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    entries = fs.readdirSync('./src/scripts/').filter(function(file) {
        return file.match(/.*\.js$/);
    });
```

and then pass it to webpack's config.

Comment: Thanks@kombucha..Is  there any way otherthan fs??

Comment: Not off the top of my head... But like @duncanhall said, are you even sure you need multiple entry points ?

Answer (score 10):

I had some problems with file paths in Webpack 2.4.1, so made this.
In addition to multiple entries, this also creates multiple .html files.

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const fs = require('fs');

function getEntries (){
    return fs.readdirSync('./src/pages/')
        .filter(
            (file) => file.match(/.*\.js$/)
        )
        .map((file) => {
            return {
                name: file.substring(0, file.length - 3),
                path: './pages/' + file
            }
        }).reduce((memo, file) => {
            memo[file.name] = file.path
            return memo;
        }, {})
}

const config = {
    entry: getEntries, 
    output: {
        path: resolve('./public'),
        filename: '[name].js'
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'My App',
            filename: '[name].html',
            template: './pages/_template.html'
        })
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just using `glob.sync` will result in sequential filenames, such as `0.[hash].js` and `1.[hash].js`, because `entry` expects an object with the the name of the file in the key and its location in the value, but `glob.sync` returns an array.

The following method has the benefit of producing an object with keys and values based on the filenames, you can also add additional entries, such as `vendor` and `common`. Requires lodash.

```
const glob = require("glob");
const _ = require('lodash');

module.exports = {
  entry: Object.assign({},
    _.reduce(glob.sync("./src/*.js"),
      (obj, val) => {
        const filenameRegex = /([\w\d_-]*)\.?[^\\\/]*$/i;
        obj[val.match(filenameRegex)[1]] = val;
        return obj;
      },
    {}),
    {
      vendor: [
        'lodash'
      ]
    }
  ),
  output: {
    filename: '[name].[chunkhash].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  }
}
```

The latter will produce the following object and pass it to `entry`, provided we have `index.js` and `app.js` in the `./src` directory:

```
{
    index: './src/index.js',
    app: './src/app.js',
    vendor: [ 'lodash' ]
}
```

Comment: upvoting - I used this approach and it worked beautifully. Thanks @Víctor González

Answer (score 0):

As specified above several times, the issue is, `entry:` requires it to be provided with 1 flattened array, so using `glob` (as also mentioned above), I wrote this simple-solution to resolve my issue:

```
const path = require("path");
const glob = require("glob");

const flattenedEntryFiles = () => {
    // wildcard inclusions
    const vendorCss = glob.sync(__dirname + "/src/css/vendor/**/*.css");
    const customCss = glob.sync(__dirname + "/src/css/*.css");

    // fixed path inclusions    
    const customSrcFiles = [
        __dirname + "/src/js/main.tsx",
        __dirname + "/src/css/scss/main.scss",
    ];

    // combine/flatten into 1 array
    return vendorCss.concat(customCss, customSrcFiles);
};

module.exports = () => {
    return {
        entry: flattenedEntryFiles(),
    }
}
```