# Regex in entry path while making an multiple entry points in webpack

Tags: webpack

How to use regex in path while setting multiple entry path in webpack?

directory

```
webpack.config.js

./javascripts/plugins/Alpha/plugin.js
./javascripts/plugins/Beta/plugin.js
./javascripts/plugins/Charlie/plugin.js
./javascripts/plugins/Delta/plugin.js
...
```

I want to output like this?

```
./build/resources/plugins/Alpha/Create/plugin.js
./build/resources/plugins/Beta/plugin.js
./build/resources/plugins/Charlie/plugin.js
./build/resources/plugins/Delta/plugin.js
...
```

I am able to achieve this by below config

```
{
entry: {
    "Alpha": "./resources/plugins/Alpha/plugin",
    "Beta": "./resources/plugins/Beta/plugin",
    "Charlie": "./resources/plugins/Charlie/plugin",
    "Delta": "./resources/plugins/Delta/plugin"
},
output: {
    filename: "[name]/plugin.js",
    path: "./build/resources/plugins"
},
module: {
    loaders: [
        {test: /\.js$/, loaders: ["babel-loader"]}
    ]
}
```

}

But there is a problem, even though my directory structure is same, I will have to make a new entry in `entry` key, if I add a new plugin. This way my `webpack.config.js` will keep on growing. 
I can see a pattern in my input and output directory

Input: `./javascripts/plugins/[pluginName]/plugin.js`

Output: `./build/resources/plugins/[pluginName]/plugin.js`

Is there any way I can achieve same just by writing any regex in path?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add wildcard mapping in entry of webpack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32874025/how-to-add-wildcard-mapping-in-entry-of-webpack)

Comment: As per above above link, this can be solved using `glob`. I was thinking if there is anything that webpack is providing on its own.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `fs` to scan a directory and create the entries object dynamically. That's what I do. (I am assuming your are using node at this point.)

```
const fs = require('fs');
const entryMap = {};

fs.readdirSync('./src/app/pages/')
    .filter(file => {
        return file.match(/.*\.js$/);
    })
    .forEach(f => {
        entryMap[f.replace(/\.js$/, '')] = ['./pages/' + f];
    });
```