# Webpack/Babel compiling scripts

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I'm learning webpack and babel, and there's something that's confusing me.

In most cases I'm seeing the config file with input and output like this:

```
entry: { main: './src/index.js'},
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
```

That all makes complete sense, but what if you want more than one js file to be compiled into dist? 
What if you have, for example, multiple js files that are being imported and exported?

I understand that many people will be using webpack with React, and so will simply use the compilation on the App.js file - but is this the same principle generally? For example, should I import all files that I want to be compiled into a single js file, and then use wpack/babel on that one?

I hope I'm making sense...it would be great to clarify.

Many thanks,

Raph

Comment: read https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/

Comment: you can "Accept" the best answer by clicking on check. see https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpogP.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Webpack can be configured to take multiple entry points:

```
entry: {
    app: "./src/scripts/app.js",
    vendor: "pathofsomeotherentrypoint"
},
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
},
```

We can even generate multiple bundles (one for each entry point).

```
entry: {
    app: "./src/scripts/app.js",
    vendor: "pathofsomeotherentrypoint"
},
output: {
    filename: "./dist/[name].bundle.js" 
},
```

above config will generate two bundles `app.bundle.js` and `vendor.bundle.js`

we can also include multiple files from a directory using glob pattern matching

```
var glob = require("glob");
// ...
entry: glob.sync("./src/scripts/*.js"),
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
},
```

For more explanation read references.

**References:**

https://medium.com/a-beginners-guide-for-webpack-2/multiple-entries-e1b3d83579bf

https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34545812/2073920

Comment: Thanks for this - is it possible to submit a directory as an entry point? I'll go have a read ... thanks again

Comment: @Raph117 yes it is. I have update my answer and references