# Webpack4 : multiple UNKNOWN entry points + multiple outputs

Tags: node.js, webpack, postcss

I am looking for a way to compile multiple Post-CSS(or any meta-CSS) file individually to parallel CSS files.

from

```
resource/
 - a.pcss
 - b.pcss
 - c.pcss
```

to

```
output/
 - a.css
 - b.css
 - c.css
```

In reality we have more than 200 files. 
So I have to compile every file in a folder with unknown name to parallel CSS files.

Untill Webpack3, [wildcards-entry-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wildcards-entry-webpack-plugin) has been helping us. But sadly it does not support Webpack4.

There are already answers to following situation, but I couldn't apply them to ours.

- multiple known entry points × one output
  https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/multiple-entry-points
- multiple unknown entry points × one output
  https://stackoverflow.com/a/34545812/10383041

Here is our current working config using Webpack3 and wildcards-entry-webpack-plugin

```
{
    context: path.join(__dirname, '/resource/css/page'),
    entry: WildcardsEntryWebpackPlugin.entry(`${__dirname}/resource/css/page/**/main.pcss`),
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, '/public/css/page'),
        filename: '[name].js',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(css|pcss)$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    use: cssLoaders,
                }),
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin({
            filename: '[name].css',
            allChunks: true,
        }),
        new WildcardsEntryWebpackPlugin(),
    ],
    stats,
},
```

Comment: Better to use gulp or grunt, webpack was not done to perform task runner tasks. Webpack needs known entry points to be able to work properly.

Comment: Thank you.
I was afraid of missing webpack's feature that helps me. 
Reading your comment, now I am ready to move on.

Just FYI I am likely to write small script with Node's `fs` that gives webpack config  desired entry point object.