# Bundle and minify multiple JS and CSS files with webpack - ERROR Module not found

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, glob, minify

Trying to use Webpack to bundle and minify all the JS files to a bundle.min.js file, and all the CSS files into a bundle.min.css file.

Folder structure:

```
root
|- assets
|- src
|-- js
|--- *.js
|-- css
|--- *.css
```

Code:

```
const glob = require('glob');
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'production',
    entry: {
        scripts: glob.sync('./src/js/*.js'),
        styles: glob.sync('./src/css/*.css')
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets'),
        filename: '[name].bundle.min.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: 'babel-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader']
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: '[name].bundle.min.css'
        })
    ],
    optimization: {
        minimize: true,
        minimizer: [new TerserPlugin()]
    }
}
```

When I try to run `npx webpack --config webpack.config.js`, I get the following error(s) for all the JS and CSS files:

```
ERROR in [...]
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'src\css\[...].css' in '[...]'
Did you mean './src\css\[...].css'?
Requests that should resolve in the current directory need to start with './'.
Requests that start with a name are treated as module requests and resolve within module directories (node_modules).
If changing the source code is not an option there is also a resolve options called 'preferRelative' which tries to resolve these kind of requests in the current directory too.
```

Kinda stuck at this point. Any suggestions is GREATLY appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm sure it's because of glob, maybe this will help you [Wildcards in entry points](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/370) and [How to add wildcard mapping in entry of webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32874025/how-to-add-wildcard-mapping-in-entry-of-webpack)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advice in the building errors message is clear.

> Requests that should resolve in the current directory need to start with './'.

If the path doesn't start with `'./'`, it will parse the request as a module

> Requests that start with a name are treated as module requests and resolve within module directories (node_modules).

Webpack will try to resolve the module within module directories (node_modules).

Project structure:

```
$ tree -L 3 -I node_modules
.
├── assets
│   ├── scripts.bundle.min.js
│   ├── styles.bundle.min.css
│   └── styles.bundle.min.js
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── src
│   ├── css
│   │   ├── a.css
│   │   └── b.css
│   └── js
│       ├── a.js
│       └── b.js
└── webpack.config.js
```

Two solutions:

- **Use `{ dotRelative: true }` option for `glob.sync()`**

> Prepend all relative path strings with ./ (or .\ on Windows).

E.g.

```js
glob.sync('./src/js/*.js', { dotRelative: true })
// [ './src/js/b.js', './src/js/a.js' ]
```

`webpack.config.js`:

```js
const glob = require('glob');
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'production',
    entry: {
        scripts: glob.sync('./src/js/*.js', { dotRelative: true }),
        styles: glob.sync('./src/css/*.css', { dotRelative: true }),
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets'),
        filename: '[name].bundle.min.js',
        clean: true,
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader'],
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [new MiniCssExtractPlugin({ filename: '[name].bundle.min.css' })],
};
```

- **Use [`resolve.preferRelative`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvepreferrelative) configuration**

> When enabled, webpack would prefer to resolve module requests as relative requests instead of using modules from `node_modules` directories.

This solution is also mentioned in the error:

> If changing the source code is not an option there is also a resolve options called 'preferRelative' which tries to resolve these kind of requests in the current directory too.

`webpack.config.js`:

```js
const glob = require('glob');
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'production',
    entry: {
        scripts: glob.sync('./src/js/*.js'),
        styles: glob.sync('./src/css/*.css'),
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets'),
        filename: '[name].bundle.min.js',
        clean: true,
    },
    resolve: {
        preferRelative: true,
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader'],
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [new MiniCssExtractPlugin({ filename: '[name].bundle.min.css' })],
};
```

Build logs:

```
> webpack

asset styles.bundle.min.css 76 bytes [compared for emit] (name: styles)
asset scripts.bundle.min.js 34 bytes [compared for emit] [minimized] (name: scripts)
asset styles.bundle.min.js 0 bytes [compared for emit] [minimized] (name: styles)
Entrypoint scripts 34 bytes = scripts.bundle.min.js
Entrypoint styles 76 bytes = styles.bundle.min.css 76 bytes styles.bundle.min.js 0 bytes
orphan modules 3.23 KiB (javascript) 1.83 KiB (runtime) [orphan] 12 modules
cacheable modules 136 bytes (javascript) 74 bytes (css/mini-extract)
  javascript modules 136 bytes
    modules by path ./src/js/*.js 36 bytes
      ./src/js/b.js 18 bytes [built] [code generated]
      ./src/js/a.js 18 bytes [built] [code generated]
    modules by path ./src/css/*.css 100 bytes
      ./src/css/b.css 50 bytes [built] [code generated]
      ./src/css/a.css 50 bytes [built] [code generated]
  css modules 74 bytes
    css ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/css/b.css 37 bytes [built] [code generated]
    css ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/css/a.css 37 bytes [built] [code generated]
webpack 5.88.1 compiled successfully in 245 ms
```

package versions:

```json
"css-loader": "^6.8.1",
"glob": "^10.3.1",
"mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.7.6",
"webpack": "^5.80.0",
"webpack-cli": "^5.0.2"
```

*Note: For better demonstration, I simplified the example, removed some loaders, plugins and configuration. Because they are not the cause of the problem.*

Comment: THANK YOU! Tried the `dotRelative` option version, and came back with the same error as I originally posted. Then, tried the `preferRelative` version, and worked! Now... one thing that happens it builds and empty `styles.bundle.min.js` file - which I saw in your build log. Is it because of the how the output for the entry points is set up? Any way of preventing this?

Comment: @thelos999 see https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin/issues/518 and https://github.com/webdiscus/webpack-remove-empty-scripts